# Не правильный вывод программы

Tags: python

```
def calc_stat(listened):  # от англ. calculate statistics, посчитать статистику
    t = 0
    for i in listened:
        t += int (i)
        m = t//60
        return (f'Вы прослушали {i} песен, общей продолжительностью {m} минут.') # напишите код функции calc_stat
   
print (calc_stat([189, 148, 210, 144, 174, 158, 163, 189, 227, 198]))
```

Вывод должен быть `"Вы прослушали N песен, общей продолжительностью M минут."`

Comment: @Юрий Если вы пишите фрагменты кода - добавляйте в начале и в конце "```".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132052/discussion-between-ma3rx-and---3-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот новый код:

```
def calc_stat(listened):  # от англ. calculate statistics, посчитать статистику
    t = 0
    for i in listened:
        t += int (i)
    m = t//60
    return 'Вы прослушали ' +str(len(listened))+ ' песен, общей продолжительностью ' +str(m)+' минут.' # напишите код функции calc_stat
   
print (calc_stat([189, 148, 210, 144, 174, 158, 163, 189, 227, 198]))
```

У вас просто были проблемы с отступами)

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в отступе, как вам уже объяснили в другом ответе, но вообще же в питоне есть специальные фунции для получения числа элементов коллекции и их суммы, "вручную" через цикл такие вещи можно не считать:

```
def calc_stat(listened):  # от англ. calculate statistics, посчитать статистику
    return (f'Вы прослушали {len(listened)} песен, общей продолжительностью {sum(listened)//60} минут.')
   
print (calc_stat([189, 148, 210, 144, 174, 158, 163, 189, 227, 198]))
# Вы прослушали 10 песен, общей продолжительностью 30 минут.
```